# Poincare conjecture 'loop' contraction issue

Tags: general-topology

According to WikiPedia's entry on [Poincare's conjecture](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Poincar%C3%A9_conjecture), the first image (on the right - five spheres):

> For compact 2-dimensional surfaces without boundary, if every loop can be continuously tightened to a point, then the surface is topologically homeomorphic to a 2-sphere (usually just called a sphere). The Poincaré conjecture asserts that the same is true for 3-dimensional spaces.

According to MathWorld's definition of [Homotopic](http://mathworld.wolfram.com/Homotopic.html):

> the circle is not contractible

These appear to be contradictory in that WP says that a loop (circle) can be contracted to a point, and MW says that it cannot. Is there a simple answer? What does a 3-loop (on a 3-sphere) look like, and is this problem therefore irresolvable?

--(edit)--

A similiar idea comes from [Cauchy's Residue theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Residue_theorem). This states that the integral of a closed contour $\gamma$ is equal to the residues inside $\gamma$, so with no residues the contour can just disappear. My idea is to find a relation from a contour with no residues to a simply-connected topological manifold as required by $Poincar\acute e$.

Comment: Can you explain better why you think the two statements contradict one another?  (Note that the first statement isn't really precise.)

Answer (score 3):

The circle is not a 2-dimensional surface!

Comment: its a degenerate one. not really relevant either, a loop is a circle, so either MW or WP is right but not both.

Comment: No, it's not - a "surface" is by definition locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$.

Answer (score 1):

Expanding on my comment to Hedi's (absolutely correct) answer:

A *surface* is a topological space $X$ which is *locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^2$* (okay fine, $X$ also needs to be Hausdorff and second countable, but that doesn't matter so much for this question). This means that for each point $x\in X$, we can find an open set $U$ containing $x$ such that $U$ and $\mathbb{R}^2$ are homeomorphic. Think of the surface $X$ as being "covered" by small, 2-dimensional "patches." (See https://en.wikipedia.org/?title=Surface, and also https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Atlas_(topology).)

The important word there is **homeomorphic**: the open set $U$ must actually *be the same as* - in the sense of topology - the space $\mathbb{R}^2$. It's not enough for $U$ to be merely "$\mathbb{R}^2$-like" in some weaker sense (in particular, it's not enough for $U$ to just be a quotient of $\mathbb{R}^2$, as $\mathbb{R}^2$ is).

In particular, it makes no sense to say that the circle is a "degenerate" surface - it just isn't a surface, at all: the circle is locally homeomorphic to $\mathbb{R}^1$, not $\mathbb{R}^2$.

So there is no contradiction between the two statements you cite.

Answer (score 0):

Let's write $S^1 = \{x \in \mathbb R^2 : |x| = 1\}$ for "the" circle. A loop in a topological space $X$ will be a continuous map $f\colon S^1 \to X$. I'll say that $f$ is contractible if I can find a continous $F\colon S^1 \times [0,1] \to X$ such that $F(z, 0) = f(z)$ for all $z \in S^1$, and $F(z,1) \equiv p$ for some some $p \in X$. The intuitive picture is that I want to continuously deform the loop inside of $X$ to a point.

*Blurb 1.* The (easier) assertion is that if $X = S^2$ then any $f$ contracts.

*Blurb 2.* This would follow from showing that if $X = S^1$ and $f$ is the identity map then $f$ is not contractible.

Pictures make both of these seem very plausible statements but they are surprisingly tricky to prove; still, proofs should be near the start of any book on algebraic topology like, say, [Hatcher's](http://www.math.cornell.edu/~hatcher/AT/ATchapters.html). Anyway, the point is that it very much matters what $X$ is.

By the way, the Poincaré conjecture does not involve higher loops or homotopy groups. Just $S^1$! Also, I haven't given the full definition of simply connected but I think any further details are just going to distract us.

Answer (score 0):

We can think of a circle as a degenerate annulus, but keep in mind that the theorem you quoted is about surfaces *without boundary*—it has nothing to say about annuli.  So if we are to apply this theorem, we should try expanding our circle to a torus $X$, which is a compact surface without boundary.

The theorem says that, if every loop in $X$ can be contracted, then $X$ is homeomorphic to the 2-sphere.  But it is not true that every loop in $X$ can be contracted, so there is no issue here.